# How to retrieve elements that have the same foreign key from a list?

Tags: python, django

I have those 2 models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_id = models.CharField(max_length=30,primary_key=True)
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class City(models.Model):
    city_id = models.CharField(max_length=30,primary_key=True)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city_country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

I have a list of cities in my `request.POST` (as string concatenation of cities ids):

```
list_cities = concat_ids.split(',')
```

for every `city_id` in the list above, there is a foreign key to the country. Is there a simple way to verify if the list of cities are in the same country (i.e have the same `ForeignKey` '`city_country`')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the list of country ids for every city in `list_cities`:

```
country_ids = City.objects.values_list('city_country_id', flat=True).filter(id__in=list_cities)
```

Then, check that all elements in the list are the same:

```
country_ids.count(country_ids[0]) == len(country_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the same as doing a simple `distinct().count()`, however, `distinct` doesn't work in every database (see the note in [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)). So you may get the value list and transform it into a set, which should be only 1 in length:

```
country_set = set(City.objects.filter(id__in=list_cities).values_list('city_country', flat=True))
if len(country_set) == 1:
     #...
```